# SqlServer performance Alter column from not null to null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For some reason, I need update one of my table columns from "NOT NULL" to "NULL".
The command is simple:

```
ALTER TABLE TBLOGDOCMESSAGE ALTER COLUMN PROCESSID BIGINT NULL
```

The problem is that the command is taking to much time to run. My table contains about 30M registers (but my datacenter could have more than 120M registers).
The column has a non clustered index on it and is not a FK.

There is a way of speeding up the command in SQLServer 2008 and up?

Comment: Are yo sure the original column is a `bigint`?

Comment: You could check here http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/501/posts/12769/is-alter-table-alter-column-not-null-to-null-always-expensive.aspx to see if this fits your scenario

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes it is bigint.

Comment: No, but define "too much time". SOmething like this on a non trivial machine should take - hm - a couple of minutes maximum.

Comment: @TomTom, Intel Core i5, 8gb Ram take more than 2 hours with 30M registers.

Comment: @Rafael says nothing - if anything this is an IO bound server and you likely lack the IO performance (pretty much unless you run it on a SSD For database, log AND temp).

Comment: Voting to close - let's move this over to the specialists at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important lesson is the existence of a `NULL` bitmap.

> A NULL bitmap will always be there in a table (heap or clustered
>   table) irrespective of whether the table has NULLable columns or NOT.
>   Note that we defined a UNIQUE constraint on LastName + FirstName in
>   Demo 2 and UNIQUE constraint is enforced using a UNIQUE INDEX on those
>   columns. NULL bitmap will NOT be present in a NON-CLUSTERED INDEX if
>   all the columns part of the index definition are defined as NOT NULL.
>   In our case both LastName + FirstName are defined as NOT NULL in the
>   table and that's why NULL bitmap wasn't there initially. When we
>   ALTERed the table definition, in this case the operation has to touch
>   each and every row of the table and that's why it is an expensive
>   operation. ([link](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/501/posts/12769/is-alter-table-alter-column-not-null-to-null-always-expensive.aspx))

Because your column also has a nonclustered index, the NULL bitmap is not yet present.
So I think `dropping` the nonclustered index, then issue the `ALTER TABLE` statement and `recreating` the index is probably faster here, or at least worth trying (in a safe environment :).

Comment: I've think of it, and I will test it now. My fear is the time to recreate the index will take as much longer than running the command without dropping it. I will let you guys know about the result.

Comment: Dropping the index first do the trick. It ran the command almost instantaneously. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think, dropping indexes may speedup your script. Once altered, recreate the Indexes.